# How to copy properly a file from a linux instance to an aws ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to copy some files from a linux server to an ec2 instance using jenkins that run on linux machine and I'm facing the following issue:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Copy command that I used: 
`sh 'scp -v -i /path/key.pem /path_to_my_file/file.txt user@host:/path_to_target`'

Comment: The Jenkins service account which the pipeline runs as does not have a shell configured by default. It appears that is the root cause for why your `pem` cannot be verified in the pipeline. You will likely need to approach this differently, or workaround it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using scp publickey authentication with a passphrase-encrypted private key file. The Jenkins script is not getting the passphase.

Remove the passphrase protection from the private key file, or preload the key manually into a ssh-agent,

See https://serverfault.com/questions/622767/scp-inside-sh-script-with-passphrase/622799

Comment: Solved that but now appear an error that told me that I don't have permission to copy in the destination folder. Do you know why?

Comment: The user simply does not have the correct permissions on the remote folder.  Check permissions on `home/user/path_to_target`

Comment: You see this error when your target directory is not a child of your user's home directory `/home/<user>/` or `~`. For example, if you are trying to copy files to the Linux root directory  `/` or one of its sub-directories. In this situation, either move your target directory under the user's home directory or change the ownership of your existing target directory from `root` to `<user>`. You shall **not** use the latter approach if your target directory happens to be one of the system directories such as `/bin`, `/boot`, `/dev`, `/etc`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we are expecting key in `~/.ssh/` folder, but in case of Jenkins better to an absolute path. So there can be two reason

- not picking the correct key, pass the full path like `/absolute_path/key.pem`
- > The Host key verification failed error message means that your SSH
  >   client has compared the received public key of the remote server and
  >   noticed that it does not match the stored version of the host key in
  >   ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

so try with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

[/cant-establish-ssh-connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416166/cant-establish-ssh-connection-debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-n)

If still the issue, you can post the full debug log.

if there is a permission issue, you should copy to the location where user has permission.

Should be like

```
scp -v -i /path/key.pem /path_to_my_file/file.txt user@host:/home/user/path_to_target'
```